proof of uniqueness of matrix function
Let us consider a matrix function $F(x)$ where $F(x)$ is $q \times r$ and $x$ is $p \times 1$. Let $f(x) = vec(F(x))$ be a $qr \times 1$ vector obtained after vectorizing $F(x)$. Assume that  $f(x_0)-f(x_1)$ can be written as $f(x_0)-f(x_1) = G(x_0, x_1)\times(x_0-x_1)$ where $G(x_0,x_1)$ is a $qr \times p$ matrix.
I want to show that $F(x_0)=F(x_1)$ holds if and only if $x_0=x_1$.  To prove this, i'm trying to prove that $G(x_0,x_1)$ has full column rank for any $x_0$ and $x_1$. Is this the correct direction to prove? If $G(x_0,x_1)$ has a reduced rank at some $x_0$ or $x_1$, doesn't the uniquness hold?
